# R leaflet label on hover and static label

Tags: r, leaflet

I want to use static labels and also labels that show on hover in my shiny app that uses leaflet for the maps. I am using the example from R leaflet Github repo [here](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/blob/master/inst/examples/labels.R). However, I am getting error messages shown below:

```
library(leaflet)

# Marker + Label on hover
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
addMarkers(
lng=-118.456554, lat=34.078039,
label='This is a label')
```

> Error in addMarkers(., lng = -118.456554, lat = 34.078039, label = "This is a label") : 
>     unused argument (label = "This is a label")

```
# Marker + Static Labels
 leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
 addMarkers(
  lng=-118.456554, lat=34.078039,
  label='This is a static label',
  labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T))
```

> Error in addMarkers(., lng = -118.456554, lat = 34.078039, label = "This is a static label",  : 
>     unused arguments (label = "This is a static label", labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T))

Comment: Maybe stable version of `leaflet` doesn't support these functions. You can use the development version by `devtools::install_github("rstudio/leaflet")`(On my env, leaflet ver. 1.0.2.9010, your code run).

Comment: You are right! I installed from Github and it works fine.